# Is it possible to migrate CentOS from (Mac) VMware Fusion into (Cisco VPS) VMWare ESXi?

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, vps, centos5, vmware-fusion

Is there any solution to clone CentOS (full mirror) from Mac VMware fusion to VMWare ESXi on Cisco VPS server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. VMware Converter should be able to do that conversion for you easily.